# Cannot connect to Oracle XE 11g2

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

This has been driving me crazy for two days. I recently installed Oracle Express Edition 11g2 on my localhost (Windows 7 Enterprise). I can start the database and the listener, but I am unable to connect.

When I try connecting from SQL Developer with the following parameters:

```
Username: SYSTEM
Password: ***********
Hostname: localhost
Port: 1521
Service name: XE
```

I get the following error: `An error was encountered... IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection. Vendor code 17002`
Which apparently is SQL Developer speak for `ORA-12541: TNS no listener`.

When i try to connect from an SQL Command Line:

```
SQL> connect
Enter user-name: system
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12638: Credential retrieval failed
```

My `ORACLE_HOME` is set to `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server`.

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora:

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LOCALHOST)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  ) 

#bohort  =
#  (DESCRIPTION=
#    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=LOCALHOST)(PORT=1521))
#    (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=bohort))
#    (HS=OK)
#  )
```

-

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\listener.ora:

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
#   (SID_DESC=
#    (SID_NAME=bohort)
#    (ORACLE_HOME= C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
#    (PROGRAM=dg4odbc)
#   )   
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

-

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora:

# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
```

Starting the listener seems to work fine:

```
C:\Users\<Username>>lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 04-F╔VR.-2015 10:
45:27

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
System parameter file is C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ad
min\listener.ora
Log messages written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\<Username>\listener\a
lert\log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc
)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                04-F╔VR.-2015 10:45:32
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 5 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\a
dmin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\<Username>\listener
\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

I am sure the answer is out there somewhere but two days of googling have not led to a solution ...

Comment: Open a Command Prompt (DOS Prompt) window, and invoke the `tnsping CLRExtProc`  and that will test to see if it is a TNS listener issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

Please use IP Address 127.0.0.1 instead of LOCALHOST in the listener and TNSNAMES file.

Restart the listener and try to connect again.